# Serializer - Django REST Framework - The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance

Tags: django, serialization, django-serializer

I want to populate a chartJs exactly like the example: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

I obtain this error:

```
AttributeError at /timesheet/json-month/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `working_hour` on serializer `TimesheetSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'working_hour'.
```

With this model:

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64, verbose_name = _("Title"))
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    working_hour = models.FloatField(verbose_name = _("Working time"))
    week = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "working week")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.week = datetime.datetime.strptime("{}".format(self.date), "%Y-%m-%d").isocalendar()[1]
        super(Timesheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I serialize my data like that (into my view):

```
def get_month_hours(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT 
            MONTH(date),
            SUM(working_hour)
        FROM
            timesheet_timesheet
        WHERE
            owner_id = %s
        AND
            date >= MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 12
        GROUP BY
            MONTH(date)
    """, [self.user])
    row = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return str(row)

@api_view(['GET'])
def timesheet_total_per_month(request):
    hours = ReturnHour(request.user.pk, datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1])
    timesheets = hours.get_month_hours()
    serializer = TimesheetSerializer(timesheets, many=True, read_only = True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Into my serializers.py:

```
class TimesheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Timesheet
    fields ='__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    """
    Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
    """
    return Timesheet.objects.create(**validated_data)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.owner = validated_data.get('owner_id', instance.owner)
    instance.date = validated_data.get('date', instance.date)
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.working_hour = validated_data.get('working_hour', instance.working_hour)
    return instance
```

Do you know the reason ?

thanks per advance,

Comment: one question first, what is your table name on database: `timesheet_timesheet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your method `get_month_hours` is returning string, that is why DRF is not able to serialize it. You need to return queryset from that method. You can try like this:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Sum

def get_month_hours(self):
   last_year = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)  # for more accurate result, please use python-dateutil or similar tools

    return TimeSheet.objects.filter(owner=self.user, date__gte=last_year).annotate('total_hour'=Sum('working_hour')).order_by('date')
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem only that the 'str' instance in your question was my model name.
I was using wrong serializer in the viewset i.e

```
class X_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = Xserilizer
    #serializer_class = Yserializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Mmodel.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, Initially, my code is
`serializer = FaqSerializer(faqs_obj)`

after making a change like this it worked.
`serializer = FaqSerializer(faqs_obj, many=True)`