# Django Serializers - Return the sum of values by filter

Tags: ajax, django, chart.js, django-aggregation

Following this post: [Serializer - Django REST Framework - The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589040/serializer-django-rest-framework-the-serializer-field-might-be-named-incorre/53589433#53589433)

I use this function:

```
def get_month_hours(self):
    last_year = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)  # for more accurate result, please use python-dateutil or similar tools
    return Timesheet.objects.annotate(total_hour=Sum('working_hour')).filter(owner=self.user, date__gte=last_year).order_by('date')
```

I want to populate the chart who use exactly the same code:

```
"data": [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
```

All values corresponding to the total working_hours (my models field) per month.

So, I have 2 problems:
The first, I receive this data:

```
 {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Développement intranet",
    "date": "2018-11-19",
    "working_hour": 8.5,
    "week": 47,
    "owner": 1
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Développement intranet",
    "date": "2018-11-26",
    "working_hour": 8.5,
    "week": 48,
    "owner": 1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Développement intranet",
    "date": "2018-11-27",
    "working_hour": 8.5,
    "week": 48,
    "owner": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "dev python",
    "date": "2018-11-28",
    "working_hour": 5.25,
    "week": 48,
    "owner": 1
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Développement intranet",
    "date": "2018-12-03",
    "working_hour": 8.5,
    "week": 49,
    "owner": 1
}
```

But I want to receive only one value: the sum of working_hour per month.

The second problme is: how to pass this values to my "data" ? I thinked like that:
"data" : $.ajax({
    url: '/my-json-url/',
    method: 'get',
}),

right ?

thanks per advance

Comment: for second, purpose of your `$.ajax` is get data from `get_month_hours` ?

Answer (score 1):

for first, you can try like this:

```
    return Timesheet.objects.annotate(total_hour=Sum('working_hour')).filter(owner=self.user, date__gte=last_year).order_by('date')
.values_list('total_hour', flat=True)
```

this will give you array data of `total_hour`

in api view from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589040/serializer-django-rest-framework-the-serializer-field-might-be-named-incorre/53589433#53589433) you must edit

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def timesheet_total_per_month(request):
    hours = ReturnHour(request.user.pk, datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1])
    timesheets = hours.get_month_hours()
    return Response({'data':timesheets})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i obtain this error: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on serializer `TimesheetSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `float` instance.
Original exception text was: 'float' object has no attribute 'title'.

Comment: Becase you use `serializer = TimesheetSerializer(timesheets, many=True, read_only = True)`. This serializer must have instance of model. But if you need only array data, see my edit answer

Comment: Thanks, it look better. I have {
    "data": [
        8.5,
        8.5,
        8.5,
        5.25,
        8.5
    ]
}
the current problem is the list, all of this values are for two month, so i want to find the sum per month (3x8,5 + 1x5,25). you know ?

Comment: can you give me example data of `sum per month`?. Like `{ "data": [ 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 5.25, 8.5 ] } `

Comment: We work 42,5 per week, x4 for a total of 170h per month (normally) for I want to have (exemple for january): [170,170,250,170,170,170,170,170,170,170,170,0,4] (sample with mars have hour supplement). it's the same of hour per day per month (8,5x5x4)

Comment: oups, that's an example for a year :p calcul from sum of day for month